# Warning : HTML 1300 Navigation occured?

Tags: javascript, html, windows, security

I have loaded my site in *Microsoft Edge* version 25.10586.0.0
 and *SmartScreen* is telling me that the site might be fake.

This warning is new on the site.
The console log shows;

```
HTML1300: Navigation occured.
example.com
```

example.com is my domain name.

I am using `JQuery` on my site as well as `JavaScript Promise functions` but the problem appeared after I added file download with `Ajax promise function`.

The warning shows right off the main page!

What could be causing this?

Comment: Would a CA (SSL) certificate fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From their [website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh180764%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> HTML1300
>
> "Navigation occurred"
>
> A new page was navigated to, or the current page was refreshed.
>
> This is an informational message and not an error. To filter this
>   message, right click the console pane, click Filter, and then uncheck
>   Info.

In other words: I wouldn't be too worried about it if I were you.

#### UPDATE

Effectively this is an open issue on the Microsoft Edge developer teams plate, and has been for quite some time. One of the many tickets can be seen here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/13246371/

That said, there's not much you can do until they fix Edge to follow the specs, so still, there's not much you can do.

Comment: Not to worry about the fact that Microsoft decided that my site is a phishing attempt?

Comment: their advice is pants - if I right-click the console in Edge developer tools there is no option "Filter" ! : right click the console pane, click Filter, and then uncheck Info.

Comment: @MadeInDreams I'm not sure how I missed your comment, but effectively this is an open issue on the Microsoft Edge developer teams plate, and has been for quite some time. One of the many tickets can be seen here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/13246371/

Comment: That said, there's not much you can do until they fix Edge to follow the specs, so still, there's not much you can do.

Comment: Nice Thank you. I got a lot of views on this one!