# HTML1300: Navigation occurred

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, internet-explorer, iis

I have my website that I have deployed in IIS 7 and run it in IE10. All tabs of this website working fine except one . When I click on that tab, it took me to log in page that is my default page. And when I click on back button it takes me to previous page. And When I saw it in Developer Mode, whenever i click on my desire tab, this show me following in console tab. "HTML1300: Navigation occurred." Any one have solution for this or can explain what is happening wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: Well we cannot give you anything except a link to html1300 -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275112/warning-html-1300-navigation-occured. We have to see your code.

Comment: I have go through this link, but it's not solving my problem.

Comment: Well I am not sure how to resolve this. Maybe it is indeed an empirical problem. I would highly suggest to provide us with an easy reproducible example -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/console/error-and-status-codes), it seems that this is an informational message and not an error. When a new page was navigated to, or the current page was refreshed, it might display this code.